# Multiply columns in dataframe by values given in another dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

I've been trying to accomplish this in dplyr but not been able to figure it out.

In one data frame (df1) I have columns with values.

```
|A  |B  |
|23 |43 |
|24 |11 |
```

In another data frame (df2) I have valus.

```
|Column|Value|
|A     |0.12 |
|B     |1.23 |
```

I want to somehow multiple every cell in column 'A' of df1 by the given value in df2 for that column. Seems like it should be trivial but I've not quite figured out the correct syntax. I suspect I was use mutate, but any advice would be appreciated.

Mostly trying to accomplish this in dplyr but welcome to other suggestions.

Comment: can you show in a data frame format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `mutate(across())`, and leverage `cur_column()` to subset the second data frame

```
mutate(d1, across(A:B, ~.x*d2[d2$Column==cur_column(),2]))
```

Output

```
      A     B
  <dbl> <dbl>
1  2.76  52.9
2  2.88  13.5
```

Input:

```
d1 = data.frame(A = c(23,24), B=c(43,11))
d2 = data.frame(Column = c("A","B"), Value = c(.12,1.23))
```

This can be extended to any number of columns; here is an input with three columns, A,B,C.

```
d1 = data.frame(A = c(23,24), B=c(43,11), C=c(25,16))
d2 = data.frame(Column = c("A","B", "C"), Value = c(.12,1.23, 0.75))

mutate(d1, across(where(is.numeric), ~.x*d2[d2$Column==cur_column(),2]))


     A     B     C
1 2.76 52.89 18.75
2 2.88 13.53 12.00
```

There is a much more verbose approach where d1 is pivoted longer and joined to d2, the calculation done, and the result pivoted_wider. It provides the same output:

```
inner_join(d2, pivot_longer(d1,everything(), names_to = "Column", values_to = "value")) %>% 
  mutate(value = Value*value) %>%
  select(-Value) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from=Column, values_from = value, values_fn=list) %>% 
  unnest(everything())
```

Output:

```
      A     B     C
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1  2.76  52.9  18.8
2  2.88  13.5  12
```

Comment: I thought OP asked only for column A? Otherwise I would also use `across`!

Comment: you read more carefully than me!! +1 your response! :)

Comment: I couldn't generalize this approach to more than two columns, the `x*d2[d2$Column==cur_column(),2]` indexation didn't work at all.
In my case I have to use:
`d1 %>% 
  mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~ .x*d2[cur_column()]))`. The only problem with this, is the creation of a `data.frame` for each column, but I think with some *unnesting* behaviour can be avoided. Suggestions accepted (and appreciated!) :)

Comment: perhaps provide a dataset where this is a problem, as I just extended it to three columns, without a problem - see solution/edit

Comment: I've also added a much longer, and I think unnecesary approach uses pivots and joins - it provides the same output

Answer (score 2):

Multiplies values in d1 column A with value in d2 where Column is A:

```
library(dplyr)

d1 %>% 
  mutate(A = A * d2$Value[d2$Column=="A"])
```

```
     A  B
1 2.76 43
2 2.88 11
```